# javascript countdown from d:h:m:s

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

I'm new in javascript.
My PHP script returns a value in this format

```
d:h:m:s
```

Now I would like to have a countdown which is able to countdown each second from this.

I modified a countdown. This works once a time, after the countdown "ticks" each second it returns NaN all the time. Any idea what I do wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.countdown').each(function() {
      var time = $(this).data("time").split(':');
      var timestamp = time[0] * 86400 + time[1] * 3600 + time[2] * 60 + time[3] * 1;
      var days = Math.floor(timestamp / 86400);
      console.log(time,timestamp);
      var hours = Math.floor((timestamp - days * 86400) / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor((timestamp - hours * 3600) / 60);
      var seconds = timestamp - ((days * 86400) + (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60))-1;
      $(this).data("time",""+days+":"+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
      if (hours < 10) {
        hours = '0' + hours;
      }
      if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
      }
      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
      }

      $(this).text(days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);

    });
  }, 1000);
})
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="countdown">02:03:05:59</h1>
```

Comment: Where you are decrementing time?

Comment: `timestamp -= timestamp > 0;` seems to be the _culprit_...

Comment: But it isn't. The biggest culprit is the content is no longer dd:hh:mm:ss after adding "days" and so on

Comment: Exactly.. It has to be identical for all the intervals..

Comment: I have posted an improved version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you have 2 problems here:

1. after the first execution you change the pattern of the text you display in the h1. First you have `02:03:05:59`. Then you want to write `02 days 03:05:58` into the tag. Next time you parse it, you get the error because you split at `:` and that does not work anymore as you have `days` instead of `:` as the seperator for the first part.
2. When calculating the minutes, you should also substract the days and not just the hours.

When you wan to keep the dd:hh:mm:ss format, you could do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.countdown').each(function() {
      var time = $(this).text().split(':');
      var timestamp = time[0] * 86400 + time[1] * 3600 + time[2] * 60 + time[3] * 1;
      timestamp -= timestamp > 0;
      var days = Math.floor(timestamp / 86400);
      console.log(days);
      var hours = Math.floor((timestamp - days * 86400) / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor((timestamp - days * 86400 - hours * 3600) / 60);
      var seconds = timestamp - days * 86400 - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
      if (days < 10) {
        days = '0' + days;
      }
      if (hours < 10) {
        hours = '0' + hours;
      }
      if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
      }
      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
      }

      $(this).text(days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);

    });
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="countdown">02:03:05:59</h1>
```

Comment: I've updated my code above. Showing a format like d:h:m:s is okay. But using your code script returns values too long. How to edit it so each value is 2 digits long not like currently for example: `2:03:2883:0-172760`

Comment: @peke_peke If I run my code posted in the answer it works quite well... Did you copy my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet goes from dd:hh:mm:ss to dd days, hh hours. So second time around, your tag contains non-parsable text.

I have changed it to something more precise. Something even MORE precise would be to give a timestamp in milliseconds in the future instead of something with seconds since it will take several seconds to render the page. If you round on minutes from the server, it would likely be better.

```js
var aDay = 24*60*60*1000, anHour = 60*60*1000, aMin = 60*1000, aSec = 1000;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.countdown').each(function() {
    var time = $(this).data("time").split(':');
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+parseInt(time[0],10))
    date.setHours(date.getHours()+parseInt(time[1],10),date.getMinutes()+parseInt(time[2],10),date.getSeconds()+parseInt(time[3],10),0)
    $(this).data("when",date.getTime());
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.countdown').each(function() {
      var diff = new Date(+$(this).data("when"))-new Date().getTime();
      var seconds, minutes, hours, days, x = diff / 1000;
      seconds = Math.floor(x%60); x=(x/60|0); minutes = x % 60; x= (x/60|0); hours = x % 24; x=(x/24|0); days = x;
      $(this).text(
        days    + ' day'   +(days==1?", ":"s, ") + 
        hours   + ' hour'  +(hours==1?", ":"s, ") + 
        minutes + ' minute'+(minutes==1?", ":"s, ") + 
        seconds + ' second'+(seconds==1?".":"s.")
      );
    });
  }, 500);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="countdown" data-time="02:03:05:59"></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for removing `timestamp-=timestamp>0;`! I wasn't sure why that was even in there.

Comment: @peke_peke Please see my new code which calculates the future time and counts down to that instead. It is much more precise.